# How to changes names of sections in during checkout in magento?

Tags: php, magento

i want to change names of sections as shown in this picture below.
[image]

i want to replace "Shipping Method" to only methods

Comment: search the code base for "shipping method" shouldn't be that hard

Comment: but it is a custom package

Comment: your still just searching files for text

Comment: i m not able to get this 
would you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom theme, and using a folder with the appropriate locale setting for your store (**System > Configuration > General > Locale Options > Locale**), create a *translate.csv* file with the following:

```
"Shipping Method","Your Translation"
```

Clear/refresh the Translation Cache at **System > Cache Management** and the change should take effect (may need to clear browser cache to notice).

An example filepath would be *app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv*.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to go to your admin area and go to System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Translate Inline and select yes for enabled for frontend. Then refresh your checkout page and when you hover over the text click the little icon that pops up and it will allow you to change the text. After changing the text click submit then refresh the page. You will now see your custom text.